# Why can't I join unallocated space with my NTFS partition in GParted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ntfs, ext4

I can't resize my NTFS partition named My Folder to join the unallocated space for some reasons I can't get.

[image: Screenshot from GParted]

Comment: You need to move the `ext4` partition to the other side of the unallocated so that you can add it to your NTFS partition.  Always best to make a backup of your data before you start to mess with partition resizing in case something goes wrong during it.  Also, you should do this from a Live CD/DVD and unmount the `ext4` partition before moving it.  Gparted shows a key on mounted partitions.

Answer (score 2):

If you booted from the same **hard disk** that you are trying to resize partitions on, that would explain the problem. It is error-prone and often not even possible to modify partitions on the same disk you are using. You must instead run GParted from another disk.

Instead of running it from a system that is installed on that drive, boot into a **live Ubuntu system**. Boot from a USB flash drive that an Ubuntu ISO image has been written to, just as you would do if you were installing Ubuntu. But select "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu" and then you can run GParted.

This was what happened to me. If you boot from same hard disk--I mean the hard disk where you want join or otherwise modify the partitions--It won't work. You have to use a live Ubuntu system instead.

Comment: This is likely the solution. The screenshot in the question shows a lock icon on a few of the partitions on the physical drive where the modification is being attempted, indicating that those partitions are mounted.

Comment: After the edit it looks much better ;-)

Comment: @EliahKagan thank's for editing my answer it look much better :-)